# Find the same numbers from two array

Tags: javascript

Hello to everyone please help me get the same numbers from two array with function.

```
function getIntersect(arrF, arrS){


    var arrF = [ 3, 5, 8];
    var arrS = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
    var nums = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < arrF.length; i++ ){
        for ( var j = 0; j < arrS.length; j++ ){
             if ( i == j ){
                nums.push(i);
                nums.push(j);
                return nums;
             }
        }
    }
}

document.write(getIntersect());
```

Comment: You are pushing the indexes, not the elements of the array, look at any js [documentation on accessing array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: ok,i just tried but i dd not get what i really need, can you help me?

Comment: Note you are returning way too early, the first time your if statement is true it is going to return and not continue the loops

Comment: Patrick now i get numbers but they are dublicated:D

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about debugging your code.

Comment: I understand you are looking for a vanilla JS solution. However with lodash it is `_.intersection(arrF, arrS)`
https://lodash.com/docs#intersection

Comment: _"i get numbers but they are dublicated"_ then don't push them twice

Comment: Patrick i resloved it. Thank you, what about the link which you have send me. You know i just ask question here where i do not understand what is wrong. And the link which you have send me not about the type of the questions which i ask.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code, couple of updates:

- added the parameters in function
- put the return statement outside both the `for` loops
- compare values instead of indexes
- instead of pushing both the values, push only one (since they are same)

```js
var arrF = [3, 5, 8];
var arrS = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
var nums = [];

function getIntersect(arrF, arrS){

    for ( var i = 0; i < arrF.length; i++ ){
        for ( var j = 0; j < arrS.length; j++ ){
             if ( arrF[i] == arrS[j] ){
                nums.push(arrF[i]);
             }
        }
    }
     return nums;
}

document.write(getIntersect(arrF, arrS));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with arrays `includes()` to check that if the element from the first array (`arrF`) is present in the second array (`arrS`) or not.

Since you are writing a function (`getIntersect()`), you can declare the input arrays outside the function and pass those when you call the function. In that way you can reuse the function for any other set of input.

```js
var arrF = [ 3, 5, 8];
var arrS = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
function getIntersect(arrF, arrS){ 
  var nums = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < arrF.length; i++ ){
      if ( arrS.includes(arrF[i]) ){
           nums.push(arrF[i]);
      }
  }
  return nums;
}

console.log(getIntersect());
```

Comment: i need it in function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` for simpler code.

```js
function getIntersect(arrF, arrS) {
  return arrF.filter(o => arrS.includes(o));
}

var arrF = [3, 5, 8];
var arrS = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];

var result = getIntersect(arrF, arrS);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the expected result by simply using the `reduce` function available on Array Objects in JavaScript.

```
function getIntersect(arrF, arrS){
    return arrF.reduce((p, c) => {
        if(arrS.indexOf(c) !== -1) {
            p.push(c);
        }
        return p;
    }, [])
}

//invoke helper function
getIntersect([3,5,8], [1, 2, 3, 5, 8])

//output
// [3, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the help of an hash table where you take the value as key and set this property of an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to `true`.

> ```
> {
>     3: true,
>     5: true,
>     8: true
> }
> ```

This is done for the first array and with the second array, check if the property is set and take then the value as result.

```js
function getIntersect(a, b) {
    var hash = {},
        i,
        result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        hash[a[i]] = true;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (hash[b[i]]) {
            result.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getIntersect([3, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]));
```

A shorter approach by using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the second array by using the set.

```js
function getIntersect(a, b) {
    var setA = new Set(a);

    return b.filter(v => setA.has(v));
}

console.log(getIntersect([3, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter function.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var arr2 = [5,6,7];

var arr3 = arr1.filter(function(item) { return arr2.indexOf(item) !== -1; }); 
console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: While this contains the germ of a correct solution, it has several errors.  (`obj`/`item` `==`/`!=`.)

Comment: I am mobile write now. Let me check

Comment: Edited.  Those issues are fixed.  The example is still not particularly illustrative, and it's not a function, but this is at least a simple solution tot he problem.  (Compare mine, which is similar, but uses `includes` rather than `indexOf`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much easier than most answers suggest:

```js
const getIntersect = (a1, a2) => a1.filter(val => a2.includes(val))

console.log(getIntersect([3, 5, 8, 12], [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getIntersect(arrF, arrS){

    var arrF = [ 3, 5, 8];
    var arrS = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
    var nums = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < arrF.length; i++ ){
        for ( var j = 0; j < arrS.length; j++ ){
             if ( arrF[i] == arrS[j] ){
                nums.push(arrF[i]);
             }
        }
    }
    return nums
}
document.write(getIntersect());
```